# Mysterious "Your connection is not private" error when attempting to load Roboto font via fonts.googleplex.com

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I am unable to download the Google Roboto fonts in the website I am working on. I receive a `Your connection is not private` message when trying to download from `fonts.googleapis.com`.

- Using recent Chrome browser
- Other's do not have this problem when running the same code on different machines, on the same network
- This problem still continues in incognito mode with extensions disabled.

This is how the fonts are included in our website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

This the full error message I see when I open the fonts.google.com url directly:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from fonts.googleapis.com 
(for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

--- 

fonts.googleapis.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Chrome 
tried to connect to fonts.googleapis.com this time, the website sent back unusual and 
incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be 
fonts.googleapis.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your 
information is still secure because Chrome stopped the connection before any data was 
exchanged.

You cannot visit fonts.googleapis.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network 
errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.
```

This error has occurred for me several times in previous months and seems to disappear at random. No one else on my team has had this issue.

Comment: This is a well known issue in Chrome, as derived problem from cache, proxy or user navigation, not related to your implementation. I will vote to close since I consider this question is valid but for stack user

Comment: I don't believe we have any caches, proxy's or other user navigations of interest going on

Comment: at least browser configuration. what about firefox?